# Ruby on Rails - Merit Gem grant_on Not Being Triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, badge, merit-gem

So I just installed the [merit gem](https://github.com/merit-gem/merit) and have been using it to implement badges within my application.  I define the badge inside the `config/initializers/merit.rb` file as so:

```
badge_id = 0
[{
  id: (badge_id = badge_id + 1),
  name: 'badge-one',
  custom_fields: { test_id: 'sample_id' }
}].each do |attrs|
  Merit::Badge.create! attrs
end
```

This badge is rewarded to the user when the user is created.  The user is created within the `user_controller.rb` within the `create` method:

```
grant_on 'user#create', badge_id: 1, badge: 'badge-one', to: @user
```

For some reason when a new user is created the the badge is never rewarded.  When I type `Merit::Badge.find(1)` I see that the badge is indeed defined.  However, when I type `User.first.badges` into my console it returns an empty array.  Why isn't the badge being rewarded to the user when they sign up?  Please let me know if you need any additional information to help out with solving this issue.

**Edit To Provide More Information**

Here is what I get when I run in `Merit::Badge.find(1).inspect` inside the console:

```
#<Merit::Badge id: 1, name: \"badge-one\", level: nil, description: nil, custom_fields: {:test_id=>\"sample_id\"}>
```

Comment: `puts Merit::Badge.find(1).inspect`?

Comment: That produces an output that is almost exactly the same as just `Merit::Badge.find(1)`. @TarynEast

Comment: Yes, but I want to actually see it :)

Comment: ie, don't just tell me you looked at the merit badge... show us.

Comment: For sure will post it in an edit!

Comment: I'm using Ruby on Rails Version 4.1.1 which isn't the latest.  Could that cause merit not to work correctly? @TarynEast

Comment: sadly I'm not an expert on merit (I've never used it)... was just curious in case there was some kind of id-mismatch, or some other obvious ruby thing to check.

Comment: Do you use an authentication gem? Can you post the contents of your `UsersController`?